# How can i send ARP request in android?

Tags: android

I want to find the devices in the Wi-Fi using arp.
(It must be arp, not icmp packet)

I found a similar app on the Play Store, and It was sending Arp.

[Captured on WireShark (192.168.0.22 is android)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWgPm.png)

Is there any api or function available?

I don't know where to start.

I would appreciate any link or document that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cause an ARP packet to be sent if you attempt to reach an IP, which you can do by many ways. One convenient way is:

```kotlin
InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.22")?.isReachable(2000)
```

which will send an ARP followed by a ICMP ping packet to the address you pass in.